# Where to initialize child controls on TCustomControl

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

I'm trying to create a simple custom control using Borland C++ Builder 6.  In this case, I am trying to create a TPageControl with a single TTabSheet on it.  I am having trouble figuring out the proper place to initialize these child controls.  At the moment I am initializing everything in the constructor.  Everything compiles fine, but when I attempt to place the control onto a form, the Borland IDE gives me an error "Control '' has no parent window" or something very similar.  I've found out that the line that is causing this specifically is the setting of the TTabSheet's PageControl property.

The code for my control is below:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>

#pragma hdrstop

#include "TestControl.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TTestControl *)
{
    new TTestControl(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TTestControl::TTestControl(TComponent* Owner)
    : TCustomControl(Owner)
{
    pageControl = new TPageControl(this);
    pageControl->Parent = this;

    tabSheet = new TTabSheet(pageControl);
    tabSheet->Parent = pageControl;
    tabSheet->Caption = "Page 1";
    tabSheet->PageControl = pageControl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TTestControl::~TTestControl()
{
    pageControl->Free();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Testcontrol
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
         TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TTestControl)};
         RegisterComponents("Test", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated--I'm finding that due to the age of this particular technology I'm not having much luck finding resources on this.

Comment: Look at one of the existing VCL controls source code and see how it's done there.

Comment: @RawN Any suggestions of a control in particular to look at?  Does the vcl even contain controls composed of other controls as I am trying to do?

Comment: Look at any compound control. Yes. Ctrl + mouse click will take you to the source code inside C++ Builder IDE.

Comment: Well it looks like what I really wanted was a Frame.  Much less of a pain for what I want to do.  @RawN I've done plenty of searching on this issue over the past couple days--both on how to initialize a PageControl and how to set properties on a control.  And most of what I've seen is setting properties in the constructor, with the caveat that you can't set properties that require a window handle.  I've seen people setting those properties in CreateParams.  In this case, neither works and I'm very uncomfortable just guessing at something that might work.  Documentation is sorely lacking...

Comment: @erikjw `CreateParams()` is the wrong place to initialize window-dependent properties. The window does not exist yet. `CreateWnd()` is more appropriate.

Comment: @erikjw - I agree with you. The documentation is lacking "abundantly". Here is my experiment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859524/where-to-initialize-subcomponent-parent